# production remote graphical login

Tags: vnc, xinetd

I have been doing a lot of searching for how to set up Ubuntu to allow remote users to graphically login.  Most of them have you set up a vnc server per user.  This is idioc in a normal production setting (like 10k users).  The ones that show how to do it via xinetd for multiple users I have simply not been able to get to work.  It seems like a real failing that linux does not have a reasonable equivalent to rdp.  User connects, gets a login screen and logs in remotely.  Really!  I am an old unix guy and this is one of the most frustrating/unreasonable situations I find on Linux.
Does anyone know of a reasonable guide on how to set up x11vnc to allow this.  Session recovery on disconnect would also be real nice.  I am even open to a CentOS solution. Thanks all!

Comment: You should have a look at x2go and move away from VNC.

Comment: I appreciate that and will take a good look at x2go.  It seems odd that the only solution is a 3rd party ppa and that the official Ubuntu repo does not have a solution for this.